# I recently install Ubuntu 21.04 from 20.04 LTS and now want to go back to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without any data loss

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

Recently I installed Ubuntu 21.04 and I think that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was better so I was thinking if I could go back to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without any data loss than it would be awesome.I have an bootable USB if it could help. And also if possible then I also dont need my applications to get uninstalled.

Comment: Back up all the data you need to save and reinstall. These are 2 different streams, one LTS one not.

Comment: You haven't said if this was a desktop or server release. You can re-install without touching user files, and have the system automatically re-install your additional packages (if available for the new release in Ubuntu repositories) which is great for desktop installs; however as system directories are wiped (prior to re-install) some server apps lose configs and need restore. No user file (stored in $HOME) is touched unless format is selected; however if you used features in 21.04 that aren't available in the prior 20.04 release the programs aren't aware of, it can have negative effects

Comment: I QA-test Lubuntu for example (as well as other *flavors*, and regularly jump systems from one release to another QA-testing the release I was talking about in prior comment... My music (mp3s etc) & chosen application I play it on survive re-installs, which of late has been 20.04.3, 21.04, *impish* & even 18.04.6 in various jumps.. I've had ill effects though thus my warning; so going backwards is usually flawless but can have ill effects on same application data (you need to check on a program by program basis what the effect will be; or just try it on a VM etc & see for yourself)

Comment: How does this impact the Ubuntu wiki - you've provided no pages that it relates to? so please clarify how it relates to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/